# Como faço pra setar o state do pai através de inputs no filho ? no react?

Tags: javascript, react, component

Meu problema é o seguinte eu estou fazendo uma aplicação de IMC, e pretendo trocar só o corpo da tela quando for aparecer o resultado, sem atualizar a pagina . o meu grande problema é que não consigo usar o inputs feita em um component pra alterar o state do pai que é onde esta o peso a altura e a idade.

Pai

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Inputs from '../../components/home/index.js'
import { Container, Title} from './styles';

export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    peso: 0,
    altura: 0,
    idade: 0,
  }

  handleWeight = (e) => {
    this.setState({ peso: e.target.value })
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  handleHeight = (e) => {
    this.setState({ altura: e.target.value })
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  handleAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({ idade: e.target.value })
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  submitResult=()=>{
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>Imc Sincero</Title>
        <div>
          <Inputs  SetWeight={this.handleweight} Setheight={this.handleHeight} Setage={this.handleAge} />
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Filho :

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Input } from './styles';

export default function Inputs(SetWeight,Setheight,Setage) {
    return (
        <>
        <Input>
            <span>Peso(g):</span>
            <input type="number"   onChange={SetWeight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Altura(m)</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={Setheight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Idade</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={Setage}></input>
        </Input>
        </>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, você está enviando por props as funções que vão alterar o estado do componente pai. Como você colocou o console.log em cada função, acredito que o problema seja que estas funções não estão sendo executadas.

Tem duas formas de resolver o problema, ambas alterando o componente filho. Segue abaixo:

Exemplo 1:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Input } from './styles';

const Inputs(props) {
    return (
        <>
        <Input>
            <span>Peso(g):</span>
            <input type="number"   onChange={props.SetWeight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Altura(m)</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={props.Setheight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Idade</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={props.Setage}></input>
        </Input>
        </>
  )
}
export Inputs;
```

Exemplo 2:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Input } from './styles';
class Inputs extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <>
        <Input>
            <span>Peso(g):</span>
            <input type="number"   onChange={this.props.SetWeight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Altura(m)</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={this.props.Setheight}></input>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <span>Idade</span>
            <input type="number"  onChange={this.props.Setage}></input>
        </Input>
        </>
    )
    );
  }
}
export default Inputs;
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado to aprendendo ainda teno muitas duvidas vlw mesmo. !